# Microsoft RDLC TextBox background image can't scale?

Tags: rdlc

I am using Microsoft rdlc for making report and need to add background image to the textbox but it shows part of the image (I know I can just make an image of smaller resolution but I need this one because of the resizing). 
I can't find anything for scaling.

Comment: to my knowledge there isn't that option for background images. You need to just prepare the image at 96 dpi and cross your fingers. If there is a way you can know the size the box will be before the report renders you can dynamically adjust the image and pass it to the report so it is the correct size.

Comment: I set the image from 300dpi to 96dpi and it is now looking much better. Thanks